# Is the meta fb:page_id still alowed on a website ?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta

I'm implementing Open Graph on website.

As mentionned on Facebook insights documentation, it's allowed to put meta like this one :

> meta property="fb:page_id" content="your_page_id"

But the Facebook [debugger tool showed an error](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.clubic.com) :

> Extraneous Property:  Objects of this type do not allow properties
>   named fb:page_id.

Other websites seems to have the same error like Mashable.com

In other hand, on [another documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/), the page administration seems to be only working with fb:admins and/or fb:app_id. But no mention of the fb:page_id.

So what the states of the fb:page_id meta on a website ?

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you describe appears to be a bug. The issue has been submitted to Facebook and accepted:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/144705805635591/?browse=search_4f0323eb790c29273088132.

It has now been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer for that but I'm looking for one as well. It wasn't a requirement for OGP to function but was for page insights.
As of late I can't seem to see fb:page_id referenced anymore on ogp.me or facbook's docs.